# Spark joining DataFrames and aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is sort of a contrived example, but captures what I am trying to do using Spark/Scala

Pet Types

```
val pets = Array(Row(1,"Cat"),Row(2,"Dog"))
val petsRDD = sc.parallelize(pets)
val petSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id",IntegerType),StructField("type",StringType)))
val petsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(petsRDD,petSchema)
```

Pet Names

```
val petnames = Array(Row(1,1,"Tigger","M"),Row(2,1,"Winston","M"),Row(3,1,"Snowball","F"),Row(4,2,"Spot","M"),Row(5,2,"Barf","M"),Row(6,2,"Snoppy","M"))
val petnamesRDD = sc.parallelize(petnames)
val petnameSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id",IntegerType),StructField("pet_id",IntegerType),StructField("name",StringType),StructField("gender",StringType)))
val petNamesDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(petNamesRDD,petNameSchema)
```

From here i can join the dataframes ...

```
val join = petsDF.join(petNamesDF, petsDF("id") === petNamesDF("pet_id") ), "leftouter")
```

Results

```
+---+-----+---+--------+---------+------+
| id| type| id| pet_id | name    |gender
+---+-----+---+--------+---------+------+
|  1|  Cat| 1 | 1      |Tigger   | M
|  1|  Cat| 2 | 1      |Winston  | M
|  1|  Cat| 3 | 1      |Snowball | F
|  2|  Dog| 4 | 2      |Spot     | M
|  3|  Dog| 5 | 2      |Barf     | M
|  3|  Dog| 6 | 2      |Snoopy   | F
+---+-----+---+--------+---------+------+
```

I would like to flatten the results so it looks something like this so I can map the results into a something for more processing.

```
((1,"Cat"),(1,"Tigger","M"),(2,"Winston","M"),(3,"Snowball","F"))
((2,"Dog"),(1,"Spot","M"),(2,"barf","M"),(3,"Snoopy","F"))
```

I started looking at UserDefinedAggregateFunctions but I could not really get it to work. I did not try that hard, but it seems like this was not a good fit.

I also looked as using a map to transform each petDF row into a petDF (list of petNames), but nested DF are not allowed.

I am hoping that I am missing something built into Spark or for an idea to get this to work. I am new to Spark/Scala.
Thanks

Comment: What do you imagine the type of `((1,"Cat"),(1,"Tigger","M"),(2,"Winston","M"),(3,"Snowball","F"))
((2,"Dog"),(1,"Spot","M"),(2,"barf","M"),(3,"Snoopy","F"))` to be?

Comment: sorry...a tuple of tuples

Comment: But then I don't know the type of my tuple until runtime... that wouldn't make much sense, right?

Comment: Was thinking that the tuple would look like `(petSchema, (Array(petNameSchema)))` as the structure type which we could extract from the DF.schema(s) at runtime. The join.schema looks like a union of the parts schema

Comment: What was the result of above? Which Spark version you are using ?

Comment: Using Spark 1.6. The tuple structure would be `(petSchema, (Array(petNameSchema)))`  That is how I would like to create it. Thanks